Getting GridDB Circular Reference Error When Creating Forced Views with SELECT Statements
I'm encountering an issue while trying to create a view in GridDB database that involves other views. Specifically, I have three views (akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.composite_product, akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.currency, akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.direction) that I'm using to create a new view named exchange.
CREATE VIEW akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.composite_product AS 
SELECT COMPOSITE_PRODUCT_KEY AS composite_product_key
     ,PRODUCT_KEY AS product_key
     ,PERCENTAGE_ALLOCATION AS percentage_allocation
     ,QUANTITY_ALLOCATION AS quantity_allocation
     ,BATCH_DATE_TIME AS row_update_date
FROM akjsplatest_UDM.akjsplatest_UDM_CDS.V_COMPOSITE_PRODUCT;

CREATE VIEW akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.currency AS 
SELECT CURRENCY_CD AS currency_cd      
,CURRENCY_DESC AS currency_desc      
,CURRENCY_SYMBOL AS currency_symbol  
, COUNTRY_CD AS country_cd 
,ROUND_AMOUNT_ZEROES AS round_amount_zeroes
FROM akjsplatest_UDM.akjsplatest_UDM_CDS.V_CURRENCY;

CREATE VIEW akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.direction AS 
SELECT DISTINCT DIRECTION_CD AS direction_cd      
,DIRECTION_DESC AS direction_desc       
FROM akjsplatest_UDM.akjsplatest_UDM_CDS.V_DIRECTION;


i tried to create exchange view:
CREATE FORCE VIEW akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.exchange AS 
SELECT cp.composite_product_key,
       cu.currency_cd,
       cu.country_cd,
       di.direction_cd
FROM akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.composite_product cp
JOIN akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.currency cu ON cp.product_key = cu.currency_cd
JOIN akjsplatest_UDM_BCV.direction di ON cu.currency_desc = di.direction_desc;


when i am executing this query, i am getting error as follows even though i am using FORCE to create view:
ERROR: Circular reference detected in view 'exchange'. 
can anyone tell why this error is coming and hints to remove this error so that exchange view can be successfully created?

May not resolve that error, but I don't see cu.country_cd in your currency view.

Are the sources for the views also views i.e. is V_COMPOSITE_PRODUCT a view? If so, you’ll need to update your question to show the chain of views back to actual tables. Just out of interest, why are you creating views that just select columns from a single source - what’s the benefit of having the view rather than just querying the source?
